# How to disable scheduled task services

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, malware

As I am still fighting with [Conficker  infection](https://serverfault.com/questions/57580/strange-scheduled-tasks-on-windows-server-2003) on my Win Server 2003.
I will like to temporarily disable scheduled task services on server.
Until I can be sure that infection of network is over.

Comment: Are you asking a question or making a statement? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/dd452420.aspx

Comment: Sory my mistake, I should asked How to disable ?

Comment: I assume you mean "temporarily" because "temporally disable scheduled ..." means something like "disable a schedule on a scheduled basis" (rather than on a one-shot, temporary, basis).

Comment: Do you want to disable all tasks or just a task? why not just disable the task via the gui or does conficker interfere with the task scheduling process?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson I mean temporarily,But my English is terrible and 

@tony roth My problems that Conficker again and again setting schedueld tasks. After I do a cleaning a server and deleting they came bak. So I wanted to disable scheduled tasks services at all.

Comment: The best and most thorough remedy is a complete reinstall, known as "nuke it from orbit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about opening services.msc and stopping the Task Scheduler service? Or net stop schedule from the command prompt. Or sc stop schedule. sc gives you a lot of other options too.